# CDI do i need producer for objects with default constructor?

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-weld, weld

In my project i use weld se. I have a problem injecting ["GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy"](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregate/GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy.html) into one of my constructors. This object has a default no argument constructor. Beans.xml is set to discover "all". But i get `unsatisfied dependency for type GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy`.

Do i need to create a producer to just return `new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy()`? Or what else could cause the problem?

(The project already uses many `@Produces` and qualifiers. So the cdi stuff works in general.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

If you need an injection of the 3rd party classes (like from Apache Camel in your case) the best way is to create a `Producer method`. Default scope will be `@Dependent`.

Comment: thats too bad, but thanks. I came from google guice injection and guice is able to inject all classes with 0-arg constructor.

Comment: @dermoritz please correct me I've misunderstood you, but Guice is basically the same here. Because you still have to write a line `bind(GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy)`, or write a one-line producer method. CDI is not different here.

Comment: no if i directly inject "GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy" if i want to inject AggregationStrategy then i have to bind.